# How to fix subprocess.py", line 1438, in _execute_child hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args, FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]

Tags: python

I am trying to build a function that captures your voice and turns it into text with Whisper from OpenAI.

This is my code :

```
import whisper
import sounddevice as sd
from scipy.io.wavfile import write
import wavio as wv
import os

# Sampling frequency
freq = 44100

# Recording duration
duration = 5

# Start recorder with the given values
# of duration and sample frequency
print("Début de l'enregistrement")
recording = sd.rec(int(duration * freq),
                   samplerate=freq, channels=2)

# Record audio for the given number of seconds
sd.wait()
print("Fin de l'enregistrement")

# This will convert the NumPy array to an audio
# file with the given sampling frequency
write("audio/recording.wav", freq, recording)

model = whisper.load_model("base")
result = model.transcribe("audio\\recording.wav", fp16=False)
print(result["text"])
```

This is my error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\bertr\Documents\Eliott\Code\Ooshot\Projet Whisper\main.py", line 28, in <module>
    result = model.transcribe("audio\\recording.wav", fp16=False)
  File "C:\Users\bertr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\whisper\transcribe.py", line 84, in transcribe
    mel = log_mel_spectrogram(audio)
  File "C:\Users\bertr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\whisper\audio.py", line 111, in log_mel_spectrogram
    audio = load_audio(audio)
  File "C:\Users\bertr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\whisper\audio.py", line 42, in load_audio
    ffmpeg.input(file, threads=0)
  File "C:\Users\bertr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ffmpeg\_run.py", line 313, in run
    process = run_async(
  File "C:\Users\bertr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ffmpeg\_run.py", line 284, in run_async
    return subprocess.Popen(
  File "C:\Users\bertr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 969, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\bertr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1438, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I already tried these solutions but none succeeded :

- https://discuss.python.org/t/filenotfounderror-winerror-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified/9757/8
- https://discuss.ray.io/t/winapi-createprocess-executable-args-filenotfounderror-winerror-2/5943/9

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

The use of whisper implies ffmpeg.
As explained in [https://github.com/openai/whisper][1]
".It also requires the command-line tool ffmpeg to be installed on your system, which is available from most package managers:

```
# on Ubuntu or Debian
sudo apt update && sudo apt install ffmpeg
# on Arch Linux
sudo pacman -S ffmpeg
# on MacOS using Homebrew (https://brew.sh/)
brew install ffmpeg
# on Windows using Chocolatey (https://chocolatey.org/)
choco install ffmpeg
# on Windows using Scoop (https://scoop.sh/)
scoop install ffmpeg
```

"
Install should be checked with : ffmpeg –version.
The PATH should also be updated with C:\ffmpeg\bin or the correct place where ffmpeg is installed